# How to setup Kubernetes nodeport service timeout?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

How to change Kubernetes NodePort service timeout?

I have tested it by running infinite loop php code using apache2 webserver but after 3 minutes it ended up with 504 gateway timeout from nginx. I can guess that it handled by NodePort service Kubernetes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the service aspects in Kubernetes are handled by the [`kube-proxy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/) and/or regular iptables, so there is not a TCP connection timeout per se. If you are looking at lower-level primitives you could look at [TCP timeouts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136921/54556) at the Linux kernel level ⏳, but typically those have defaults that are reasonable.

You provided very few details on your question  but assuming you are using an Nginx ingress controller, you can weather the services/pods that actually service traffic are actually up and receiving traffic at the specific moment that you are getting those timeouts.  You can also tweak the timeouts ⏳ at the Nginx ingress controller level using [annotations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136921/54556) or the [configmap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#configuration-options)

✌️

Answer (score 1):

NodePort simply exposes pod's ports on the node, health checking is not its functionality.

I guess you are looking for `livenessProbe` that can be defined per container. Its purpose is to check whether a container is healthy and if that is not the case, it will kill it and then restart is so that the container is returned to its original/normal state.

Example of HTTP liveness probe that checks health of a container every 5 seconds by hitting port 80 and path `/` of the container.

```
livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
          port: 80
          path: /
      periodSeconds: 5
```

more configuration detail [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)